# How to create new field based on other field for shapefile arcgis

Tags: python, arcgis, shapefile

I'm new to using arcmaps, and I have a shapefile I want to modify by adding new fields. The shapefile has district names and boundaries, and I want to add GDP per capita to the shapefile by district names.

So simply put, my shapefile has one field that is important for modification: district name; I have my separate list of district name and gdp per capita, in csv file.

I know how to deal with lists and dictionaries in python, but how can I use these to modify the shapefile fields?

Comment: For questions about ArcMap and ArcPy I recommend the [gis.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

To add a field, use the [`AddField`](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/tool-reference/data-management/add-field.htm) tool, e.g.

```
arcpy.AddField_management(in_table, field_name, field_type)
```

To calculate into that field, use an [`UpdateCursor`](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-data-access/updatecursor-class.htm) (linked help page and following example assume ArcMap 10.1+). To calculate `FIELD3 = FIELD1 / FIELD2`, e.g.

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(shapefile, ['FIELD1', 'FIELD2', 'FIELD3'] as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        row[2] = row[0] / row[1]    # index here matches index of fields listed above
        cursor.updateRow(row)
```